# Is there a differentiable function that does not satisfy the usual sufficient conditions for differentiability?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

By "the usual sufficient condition" I mean this
**Claim:** If a function $f:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ has partial derivatives in a neighborhood $D$ of $(x_0,y_0)$, and if these are continuous at $(x_0,y_0)$, then $f$ is differentiable at $(x_0,y_0)$
(and equivalent in $\mathbb R^n$)

Comment: Yes definitely; even in the case $n=1$, there are examples of functions which are differentiable at a point, but not continuously differentiable at that point. The same is true in any dimension.

Comment: Ok, so I wasn't thinking about the trivial case. You say $x^2sin(1/x)$ should do the job, right? May I ask you how "often" in actual multivariate calculus one has a differentiable function for which the **claim** doesn't work?

Comment: Yup, that works in one dimension; I'm not sure about any theorems which discuss how "large" the space of differentiable, but not continuously differentiable functions is (eg. if it's dense in some other space or stuff like that). Here's a very vague statement though : I've seen many differentiable functions which are not continuously differentiable in multivariable calc. A multivariable example can be obtained by trivially modifying the single variable one: consider $f: \Bbb{R}^n \to \Bbb{R}$ defined as $f(\xi) := \lVert \xi\rVert^2 \sin \left( \dfrac{1}{\lVert \xi \rVert}\right)$

Comment: Although you didn't explicitly ask this, it is also possible to have functions which have all the directional derivatives exist at a point, but the function not be differentiable. For example, take any function $f: V \to W$ ($V,W$ vector spaces) which is homogeneous, but not linear. Then, such a function cannot be differentiable. Explicit examples include $f(x,y) = \dfrac{xy}{x^2 + y^2}$ or $\dfrac{x^2y^2}{x^4 + x^2y^2 + y^4}$ (all defined to be $0$ at the origin).

Comment: Thak you very much. But are those functions even continuous at the origin? They don't look so. Maybe e should add a degree at the numerator. Anyway I can't see the reason to this, but it's really interesting because it explains all the usual examples at once.

Comment: No they're not (choose two different paths like x=0 and y=x and take the limit as x approaches 0). I merely have those examples as an illustration of how bad things can be (and as you point out, they can be so bad as to not even be continuous, yet have all the derivatives exist)

Comment: all the directional derivatives*